# How to stop polling using timeout in fetch request while adding intervals

Tags: javascript, long-polling, ajax-polling

I am polling for my report adding 5 seconds interval between each request.

```
const addDelay = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout))

export const myReport = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_REQUEST
  })

  let url = `/admin/dashboard/report.js?project_id=${projectId}&tool_id=${toolId}`

  try {
    const subscribe = async (uri) => {
      let response = await fetch(uri, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'x-api-token': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
      const resBody = await response.json()
      if (resBody.status === 'success') {
        window.location.href = resBody.url
        dispatch({
          type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_SUCCESS
        })
      } else {
        await addDelay(5000)
        await subscribe(url)
        //   return;
        // setTimeout(() => {
        //   dispatch({
        //     type: constants.SHOW_DOWNLOAD_POPUP
        //   })
        //   return;
        // }, 15000);
      }
    }
    subscribe(url)
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_FAILURE,
      errorMessage: error.status
    })
  }
}
```

Now, here I want to stop the polling after 15 seconds and show a popup.

The issue is I cannot add setTimeout here because I am using `async`. Also it won't stop calling `subscribe` method again and again as it keeps getting in else part, `return` is not working.

I want to get out of else part, stop calling the function and show popup after 15 seconds over. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement can't possibly work because this function is [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) - it'll never get there if the fetch keeps failing. What about just adding an index to track how many times you've retried subscribe?

```
const addDelay = (timeout) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));

const failed = 0;

export const myReport = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_REQUEST,
  });

  let url = `/admin/dashboard/report.js?project_id=${projectId}&tool_id=${toolId}`;

  try {
    const subscribe = async (uri) => {
      let response = await fetch(uri, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'x-api-token': `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      const resBody = await response.json();
      if (resBody.status === 'success') {
        window.location.href = resBody.url;
        dispatch({ type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_SUCCESS });
      } else {
        if (failed >= 3) {
          // whatever you want to do on fail
        } else {
          failed += 1;
          await addDelay(5000);
          await subscribe(url);
        }
      }
    };
    subscribe(url);
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_FAILURE,
      errorMessage: error.status,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the amount of time that has passed since polling started and exit when it reaches zero.

```js
const addDelay = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout))

export const myReport = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_REQUEST
  })

  let url = `/admin/dashboard/report.js?project_id=${projectId}&tool_id=${toolId}`

  let remainingPollingTime = 15000 // <--------
  try {
    const subscribe = async (uri) => {
      let response = await fetch(uri, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'x-api-token': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
      const resBody = await response.json()
      if (resBody.status === 'success') {
        window.location.href = resBody.url
        dispatch({
          type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_SUCCESS
        })
      } else {
        if(remainingPollingTime <= 0) { // <--------
          dispatch({
            type: constants.SHOW_DOWNLOAD_POPUP
          })
          return
        }

        remainingPollingTime -= 5000 // <--------
        await addDelay(5000)
        await subscribe(url) 
      }
    }
    subscribe(url)
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: constants.DOWNLOAD_REPORT_FAILURE,
      errorMessage: error.status
    })
  }
}
```